# Mega code not compiling on Wemos Mega board

Tags: arduino-mega, compilation-errors

Hi I have some code that I'm trying to port from a Mega 2560 R3 to a Wemos Mega.

```
#include "SoftPWM.h"
#include ESP8266WiFi.h

// Outputs to PWM & H bridge direction
// PWMs: 
// DC_pwm, left_pwm, right_pwm = 3, 4, 5
int pwm_out[] = {3, 4, 5};
const int num_pwm = sizeof(pwm_out) / sizeof(pwm_out[0]);

// H bridge direction control: 
// dc_1, dc_2, left_1, left_2, right_1, right_2 = 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
int dir_pins[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
const int num_dir_pins = sizeof(dir_pins) / sizeof(dir_pins[0]);

// Variable for reading pin inputs
int from_r_pi_pwm = 0;
int from_r_pi_dir = 0;

void setup() {

  // Inputs from Raspberry Pi
  Serial.begin(38400);

  // Set up PWM pins
  SoftPWMBegin();
  for (int i = 0; i < num_pwm; i++)
  {
    SoftPWMSet(pwm_out[i], 0);
  }

  // Set up H bridge direction pins
  for (int i = 0; i < num_dir_pins; i++)
  {
    pinMode(dir_pins[i], OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(dir_pins[i], LOW);
  }
}

void loop() {

  // Check input from R Pi & send it to the H bridges
  while (Serial.available() < 2){}

  if (Serial.available()) {
      // read the incoming bytes:
      from_r_pi_dir = Serial.read();
      from_r_pi_pwm = Serial.read();
      Serial.print("Serial in: directions - ");
      Serial.print(from_r_pi_dir);
      Serial.print(" PWM - ");
      Serial.print(from_r_pi_pwm);
      Serial.println();
  }

  // Set direcions on H bridges
  for (int i = 0; i < num_dir_pins; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(dir_pins[i], bitRead(from_r_pi_dir, i));
    Serial.print("pin ");
    Serial.print(dir_pins[i]);
    Serial.print(" : ");
    Serial.print(digitalRead(dir_pins[i]));
    Serial.println();
  }

  // PWM to motors
  for (int i = 0; i < num_pwm; i++)
  {
    analogWrite(pwm_out[i], from_r_pi_pwm);
    Serial.print("pin ");
    Serial.print(pwm_out[i]);
    Serial.print(" : ");
    Serial.print(digitalRead(pwm_out[i]));
    Serial.println();
  }
}
```

This compiles and runs fine on a Mega & is my go to code for setting up pwm & h bridges.

So when I was playing with WiFi I selected the Wemos R1 board from the programmer & everything worked fine but if I try that with this code I get,

```
#include <avr/io.h>
                    ^ 
compilation terminated.

exit status 1 Error compiling for board WeMos D1 R1.
```

So after a bit of searching I found that I should be selecting `Arduino/Genuino Mega 2560` but now the upload keeps timing out,

```
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

Anybody come across this before?

**Edit #1:**  As per the comment below I tried setting DIP switches 1 & 2 ON and all the rest OFF (I also tried 1, 2, 3 & 4 ON and the rest OFF) but still the same compliation error if I select Wemos board.

If I select the Mega 2560 I get `ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory` which is a new error!

Comment: You cannot simply compile code for the Mega also for the WeMos. It is complete different hardware. The Arduino Mega uses an Atmega chip, while the WeMos is an ESP. You will have to go through the whole code, change the pins, check if the required hardware is available in this chip and check, if the used libraries are compatible with the ESP. Porting is mostly not an easy task.

Comment: the wemos board is a Mega & an eps on the same board. See [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-MEGA-2560-With-WiFi-Built-in-ESP8266/)

Comment: switch the dip switches 1 and 2 ON all other OFF

Comment: @Juraj tried that but still the same compliation error if I select Wemos board & if I select the Mega 2560 I get _ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wemos/Mega board and IDE setup is complex and not for the faint hearted. Here is the table for the DIP switch setting:

```
1=ON  2=ON  3=OFF 4=OFF 5=OFF 6=OFF 7=OFF 8=OFF (ATmega2560<->ESP8266)
1=OFF 2=OFF 3=ON  4=ON  5=OFF 6=OFF 7=OFF 8=OFF (USB <->ATmega2560)
1=OFF 2=OFF 3=OFF 4=OFF 5=ON  6=ON  7=ON  8=OFF (USB<->ESP8266 (Update firmware or sketch))
1=OFF 2=OFF 3=OFF 4=OFF 5=ON  6=ON  7=OFF 8=OFF (USB<->ESP8266 (communication))
1=OFF 2=OFF 3=OFF 4=OFF 5=OFF 6=OFF 7=OFF 8=OFF (All independent)
```

Table DIP switch Special Solution:

```
1=ON 2=ON 3=ON 4=ON 5=OFF 6=OFF 7=OFF 8=OFF (USB <-> ATmega2560<-> ESP8266)
USB converter CH340G connect to RX0/TX0 of ATmega2560
ESP8266 connect to RX3/TX3 of ATmega25
```

https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html for ESP8266 documentation.

Set the Additional Boards URL to http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json in preferences

Under Tools select Board then Board Manager, then install the esp8266 by ESP8266 Community

The Arduino IDE setup requires understanding what board setting and communication setting to use to build and upload a sketch.

Under Tools select Board then select the "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560"

Set the DIP switches on the actual board to `1=OFF 2=OFF 3=ON 4=ON 5=OFF 6=OFF 7=OFF 8=OFF (USB <->ATmega2560)`

That was the DIP switch and USB setup.

Ref. https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=578430.0

The error `ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory` is easy. The file name should be a string: `#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"`.